# android 5.1 Exchange email problem

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, exchange

I have a Moto G, and I just update the Android system to 5.1.  With the old system, I was able to expand and contract the size of e-mail in Exchange (by expanding and contracting two fingers on the screen; I don't know the name for this action), and the text would reformat to fit on the screen.  Now with 5.1, this doesn't work any more.  I expand the screen and the text becomes larger, but it doesn't reformat, and I lose some of the text "off screen."

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?  Thank you.

Comment: Did you try double tapping screen? That works for me on kitkat to reformat mails